# Login page. How to match username and password from database to allow user to login?

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I've created a database for users. The thing is i do not know how to apply on android Java file to execute the function for user to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check the UserName/Password against the database, if correct launch an intent to redirect the user to the next activity, if false ask the user to supply his/her credentials again.

Comment: can you help out with the database part? I've posted another question together with my code. I only manage to get the user logged in by hardcoding, not database. Check it out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155648/re-login-page-how-to-match-username-and-password-from-database-to-allow-user-to