# RE: Login page. How to match username and password from database to allow user to login?

Tags: android

I managed to create the logic for the function but I have no idea how to match it with the database. I only know how to do it the hardcoding way.

Below is how I did it. Can anyone help me with the 'guest' part which I believe an sql statement should be inserted there am I right? And I know I missed out something. Before I match the username and password, I should check whether the user exist in the database first, and then check whether the password match with the username.

So in conclusion I need help on the 'if else' statement.

```
package one.two;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private EditText etUsername;
    private EditText etPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;
    //private Button btnRegister;
    private TextView lblResult;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     // Get the EditText and Button References
        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernametxt);
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordtxt);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        //btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.msglbl);


        Button btnArrival = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnArrival.setOnClickListener(this);


    // Set Click Listener
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Check Login
        String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        if(username.equals("guest") && password.equals("guest")){
            lblResult.setText("Login successful.");
        } else {
            lblResult.setText("Login failed. Username and/or password doesn't match.");
        }
    }
});



    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatabaseActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before I match the username and password, I should check whether the user exist in the database first, and then check whether the password match with the username.

no unless Its in your requirement you don't need to make two SQLs . Better you do something like. `select count(*) from tableName where userNameField = username and passwordField = password` and check If the number of rows is > than 0 Login is Okay otherwise username OR Password is invalid

Comment: so it goes:

"if(select count(*) from tableName where userNameField = username AND passwordField = password){
            lblResult.setText("Login successful.");
        } else {
            lblResult.setText("Login failed. Username and/or password doesn't match.");
        }"

?

Comment: You need yo execute this Select Statement into Database and Check the returned Output. Check your Database Connection API for this. It might be located here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Connection.html .